# Strange "pattern not match" error on fluentd

Tags: apache, logging, fluentd

Can someone tell if its normal that fluentd raise this error in **td-agent.log** file?

```
2015-07-31 13:15:19 +0000 [warn]: pattern not match: "- - - [31/Jul/2015:13:15:19 +0000] GET http://172.31.108.218/ HTTP/1.1 200 0 \"-\" \"ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\""
```

While this is a well formated apache2 log:

```
- - - [31/Jul/2015:13:15:19 +0000] GET http://172.31.108.218/ HTTP/1.1 200 0 \"-\" \"ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\"
```

And here is the source configuration:

```
<source>
  type tail
  format apache2
  path /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/tmp/access.log.pos
  tag "apache2.varnish-access"
</source>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong there above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these **ELB-HealthChecker** line log has an empty referer ip field. And then the log doesn't match apache2 log format for fluentd.

So the way to fix that is to filter logs with **ELB-HealthChecker** user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding some way to filter out logs from ELB-HealthChecker, you can set your own `format` for the Apache access log that is a little more flexible in terms of the first couple fields. I ran into this same error when getting /server-status checks from collectd (using it to monitor for SignalFx).

Setting the source like so:

```
<source>
  type tail
  format /^(?<host>[^ ]*(?:\s+[^ ]+)*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$/
  time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
  path /var/log/apache2/access.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/apache2.pos
  tag apache2.log
</source>
```

Allows both log lines like:

```
172.18.0.2:80 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2017:19:58:38 +0000] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 508 "-" "collectd/5.7.2.sfx0"
```

As well as:

```
192.168.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:12:00:00 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "Opera/12.0"
```

You can test `format` regex matching using [Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com).

See related: [Fluentd apache log format with multiple host ip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31988293/100134)