# Fluentd apache log format with multiple host ip

Tags: regex, logging

I have a little issue with fluend log parser. I have varnish server on which I have set up the **X-Forwarded-For** parameter to content the list of ip all the host stack a http request goes through. I use this to get information in **varnishncsa** logs. This is and example of log :

```
"192.168.79.16, 192.22.10.22, 10.2.2.22 - - [13/Aug/2015:09:50:45 +0000] \"GET http://poc.mydomain.com/panier/payment/payline?notificationType=WEBTRS&token=1KB01BwKWdUhVj1222301439454223514 HTTP/1.1\" 401 0 \"-\" \"Java/1.8.0_45\""
```

In the oder hand I would like to aggregate these logs on fluentd. Then as vanishncsa logs use the apache format, I use the **apache2** flentd format for input parsing, like in this configuration :

```
<source>
  type tail
  format apache2
  path /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/tmp/access.log.pos
  tag "apache2.varnish.mydomain.com.access"
</source>
```

Now the problem is that this work when if I have only one host ip in the log, but when there multiple IPs, the fluentd agregator report a "pattern not match" warning. I mean

This matches :

```
"192.168.79.16 - - [13/Aug/2015:09:50:45 +0000] \"GET http://poc.mydomain.com/panier/payment/payline?notificationType=WEBTRS&token=1KB01BwKWdUhVj1222301439454223514 HTTP/1.1\" 401 0 \"-\" \"Java/1.8.0_45\""
```

This doesn't match :

```
"192.168.79.16, 192.22.10.22, 10.2.2.22 - - [13/Aug/2015:09:50:45 +0000] \"GET http://poc.mydomain.com/panier/payment/payline?notificationType=WEBTRS&token=1KB01BwKWdUhVj1222301439454223514 HTTP/1.1\" 401 0 \"-\" \"Java/1.8.0_45\""
```

The apache2 fluentd regex is :

```
^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
```

With this time format :

```
%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
```

I try to find out and text the right regx for that, but not found yet.

I tried this but, it doesn't work

```
 <source>
      type tail
      format format /^(?<host>\,*[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$/ 
      time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
      path /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
      pos_file /var/log/td-agent/tmp/access.log.pos
      tag "apache2.varnish.mydomain.com.access"
    </source>
```

Can someone help? And also give me a good documentaion on fluend parser pattern capturing, and a good way to the test fulentd regex.
This [Fluentd regular expression editor](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/) doesn't really help.

It always generate configuration, without giving a test result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex you can use in case you have multiple IPs:

```
^(?<host>[^ ]*(?:,\s+[^ ]+)*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo on a good Web regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/tI6tD9/1)

The `(?:,\s+[^ ]+)*` pattern matches 0 or more (`*`) sequences of `,`, 1 or more whitespace (`\s+`) symbols, and 1 or more characters other than space (`[^ ]+`).

A bit safer expression will look like:

```
^(?<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+(?:,\s*(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)*|-) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tI6tD9/3)

The `(?:\d+\.){3}\d+(?:,\s*(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)*` matches `number` + `.` + `number` + `.` + `number` + `.` + `number`, with optional identical patterns listed with a comma.

Comment: Thanks you so mush stribizhev, I got to this site, but didn't succed to make accurate tests. 
I can now test all case, I'll try now to make my log configuration work, and let you know.

Comment: The safer mode you suggest works, and it's the best way for me to be sure, the ip address is good/conventionnal. But how can I adjust this second regex to match the the host is absent? For example to match this.
**- - - [13/Aug/2015:09:50:45 +0000] "GET http://poc.mydomain.com/panier/payment/payline?notificationType=WEBTRS&token=1KB01BwKWdUhVj1222301439454223514 HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "-" "Java/1.8.0_45"**
I can do it with the first regex, but I tried with the second (and correct one for me) without success.
Thanks

Comment: I found, this is how to do it :

**^(?:(\D|(?<host>(?:\d+\.){3})\d+(?:,\s*(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)*)) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$**

Comment: Ahah, I saw yours. You did it another way than me Great !

Comment: `\D` means non-digit. Also valid. So. does it work now?

Comment: Great, please consider accepting the answer since it works for you and upvtoing if you find the answer helpful.

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're asking me to do please.....

What? How and where? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I did. Is it ok now please?

Comment: I will be very grateful if you click the tick sign below the down arrow on the left. And that will be all. Thank you.

Comment: Is it ok now? 
I didn't pay attention to these details before. I will know what to do next time.

Comment: Almost. Just there is a tick symbol on the left just below the down arrow. If you click it, the answer will be marked as accepted. It is important as it will let others know the question is answered and they won't lose time on reading through all comments or trying to come up with an alternative solution. Now it is OK.

Comment: Yes I did it just after my comments. I also read the StackExchange documentation about this to understand. I totaly agree and know how to do next time.
Thanks.